# Can't add row to DB using ContentValues.insert() Android Studio (SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: ....)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm newbie with Java and Android Studio.I'm currently trying to create a to do list application. For that, I need to store the user's input into a database. However I can create the database and the table without any problem. But each time I try to add new row into the database, an error occurs.

```
D/DatabaseHandler: ===Inside DatabaseHandler constructor===
D/DatabaseHandler: ===Inside onCreate from DatabaseHandler===
D/MainActivity: ==addToDatabase==
    /SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: test_database
    E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting STATE=14 TASK=13 ID  =1
                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: test_database (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO test_database(STATE,TASK,ID  ) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

create the database (DatabaseHandler) and create the table (onCreate()):

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "test_database", null, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "===Inside DatabaseHandler constructor===");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "===Inside onCreate from DatabaseHandler===");
      //  String database_table = "CREATE TABLE task(" + COLUMN_ID + " INT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_TASK + " INT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_STATE + " INT NOT NULL)";
        String      database_table = "CREATE TABLE task(ID INT NOT NULL, TASK INT NOT NULL, STATE INT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(database_table);
    }
}
```

and finally the function I used for add new row into the DB:

```
public int     addToDatabase(SQLiteDatabase access, String task) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==addToDatabase==");
    if (access.isOpen() == false) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[addToDatabase] Database is not Open");
        return (-1);
    }
    ContentValues   values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("ID  ", 1);
    values.put("TASK", 13);
    values.put("STATE", 14);
    access.insert("test_database", null, values);
    return (1);
```

I already try to solve the problem by myself by looking on the other existing post. It seem that it may be cause because the database wasn't create correctly. Nonetheless as you can there's any error while creating the database, only when I'm trying to add new stuff.

I also read that it could be in report with the version of the database...However, I don't really understand why..(I'm still looking into the official documentation).

Does anyone can explain me and tell me how can I fix the problem ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
access.insert("task", null, values)
```

instead of this

```
 access.insert("test_database", null, values);
```

or

if you have updated your app table name then `uninstall your app manually` and try running again.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, it work perfectly. However, I looked for uninstall my app manually on internet but didn't find anything usefull, can you by the way explain me how can I do it ? THanks

Comment: I edited my comment but you maybe not noticed it. can you please explain me by the way how can I manually uninstall my app ? Thanks :)

Comment: @S7_0 if the solution worked then you don't have to uninstall your app otherwise , goto setting app , look for app manager and look for your app and click and select uninstall , or [uninstall app](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Apps-on-Android) or depends upon you android version ,uninstall feature pops up if you long-click on your app's icon , happy coding

Comment: once you change you table name with already running app then either the app should be uninstalled manually or you have to increment the database version value by one to recreate the database with `onUpdate` inside `DatabaseHandler`

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is apparently wrong. Change the table creation query.

```
String database_table = "CREATE TABLE test_database(ID INT NOT NULL, TASK INT NOT NULL, STATE INT NOT NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you [Android Sqlite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You may edit your "DatabaseHandler" and run the project so that the change in your database doesn't occur.

I simply removed data from the application, to be opened for the first time 
and it worked for we:

[image: Like That]